# MockServer: How to Avoid Loading All Entity Sets?

Tags: sapui5

I am using [/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata) as a mock service to build a sample Fiori application.

I am using a mock server to simulate the OData service.

[image]

Every time, when I refresh the browser, it takes at least 30 seconds to load the OData service.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, it tries to load a lot of data. 
The question is, how to load all these data in the background or is there another opportunities to improve the load time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the mock server starts, ..

1. It fetches the *service metadata* (`metadata.xml`) **synchronously**.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c5c2222163377e1bb44cdb2babeee4ff6f1f9569/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/util/MockServer.js#L1129-L1132)</sup>
2. Then analyzes the metadata to determine which entity sets are defined there.
3. It then tries to fetch **all** the entity sets from the folder `mockdata`, again, **synchronously** / sequentially one by one.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c5c2222163377e1bb44cdb2babeee4ff6f1f9569/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/util/MockServer.js#L1360-L1364)</sup>

This slows down the loading process massively as you could see.

In order to mock only certain entity sets, you can assign the names, which are defined in each `<EntitySet>` within the `<EntityContainer>` in metadata, to the property `aEntitySetsNames` in the `simulate` settings map.<sup>[API](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.util.MockServer/methods/simulate)</sup>

```js
myMockServer.simulate("...", {
  sMockdataBaseUrl: "...",
  aEntitySetsNames: [ // Load only Suppliers.json and Products.json
    "Suppliers",
    "Products"
  ]
});
```

> *aEntitySetsNames:*
>   list of entity set names to fetch. This parameter should be used to improve performance in case there are a lot of entity sets but only a few are needed to be fetched. Default value is empty - in this case all entity sets will be retrieved.

---

If someone is interested, here is my experiment to load metadata as well as all the entity sets in parallel and asynchronously: [https://embed.plnkr.co/F3t6gI8TPUZwCOnA/](https://embed.plnkr.co/F3t6gI8TPUZwCOnA?show=localService%2Fmockserver.js)

Answer (score 0):

Mock server expects all JSON files to be available in UI project library.

But you are using, proper service (though its a test data) but its live not mock server.
Use it like a normal `oData` service instead mockserver.

OR create simple metadata file and reference it in `manifest.json`

```
"dataSources": {
            "mainService": {
                "uri": "/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0",
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
```

Then create simple `json` file to have data too.

[Read how to create mockserver in detail](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.mockserver.02/code/webapp%252Fview%252FApp.view.xml)